# I am trying to read and then update a value using Core Data, but when I run it, I get “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”, but when I debug it, it works

Tags: iphone, core-data, exc-bad-access

I am trying to get the hang of Core Data, and I am running into a strange issue. I have an app that uses a local notification to alert the user, whereupon the user enters my app and this method is called:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
```

When the app loads, I prompt another alert view to get some information from the user:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Did you %@?", notif.alertBody] message:@""
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No..." otherButtonTitles:@"Yes!", nil];

    [alert show];
```

And then every time this alert is shown, I want to increment a counter value in my Core Data DB, and I do that by calling this method right after I show the alert:

```
[self incrementVal];
```

Inside of this method, I read a value, turn it into an int, then pass the new number off to another method that will then save the new value in my db.

```
-(void) incrementVal{

//for reading from the db

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                 entityForName:@"score" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;

NSPredicate * pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == 2"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

NSArray * strengthVal = [managedObjectContext_ executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
armorScore * armo = [strengthVal objectAtIndex:0];
int aScor = [armo.score intValue];


aScor++;

//For updating the db

[self updateDBVal:aScor];


[fetchRequest release];




  }

  -(void) updateDBVal:(int)value{


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity2 = [NSEntityDescription 
                                entityForName:@"score" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_];
[fetchRequest2 setEntity:entity2];
NSError *error2;

NSPredicate * pred2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == 2"];
[fetchRequest2 setPredicate:pred2];

NSArray * banna = [managedObjectContext_ executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest2 error:&error2];
armorScore * bann2 = [banna objectAtIndex:0];

bann2.score = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value];

[managedObjectContext_ save:&error2];
[error2 release];
[fetchRequest2 release];
   }
```

So I don't know if this approach is ideal, but it is the one that I came up with. It runs fine when I debug it and go through each line, but when I just run it, it crashes saying Exc_Bad_Access...

What am I doing wrong? I really want to get this figured out.

Thanks!!

Comment: Usually this weird kind of behavior is caused by memory stomping. What does the stack trace say is wrong?   
Some things to try:  enable NSZombieEnabled in Executable properties/arguments. Check your NSLog statements - make sure the # of variables = # of %@ - the compiler won't catch these.

Comment: This kind of thing has driven me nuts before. Luckily the feature wasn't key to my app, so I basically ditched it. If you find a solution though, I'd be very excited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're doing wrong:

```
[error2 release];
```

Comment: I can't believe it! What a silly mistake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Brandon no worries, happens to me all the time :-)